# QPushbutton How to remove the color created by setDefault(True)

Tags: qt, pyqt

I'm currently try to custom my QPushButton in Qt (PyQt in fact). So I set StyleSheet to do it.

But the problem is that I need to set this button to Default by setDefault to True.

And if I do that, I've a sort of color drool over ... how can I get rid of it?

Here is an example:

```
button = QPushButton('login')
button.setDefault(True)
button.setObjectName('login')
button.setStyleSheet(
    """
        QPushButton#login {
            background-color: #4caf50;
            color: white;
            border: none;
        }
        QPushButton:pressed#login {
            background-color: #59b75c;
        }
    """
)
```

Button appears green, but text is not fully white... I've try to set StyleSheet on `QPushButton:default` But it does not change anything at all

Comment: I think you're missing `button.setObjectName("login")` in your code. The argument of the button constructor is for the display text.

Comment: Also, `QPushButton#login` has precedent over `QPushButton:default`. You need to use `QPushButton#login:default` to override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long searches on the internet, I finally found how to do. I've to set `outline` to `none` to remove it.

```
QPushButton#login {
    background-color: #4caf50;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
}
```

Then slobbery color disappear.

Answer (score 2):

I can see you have a small error in your code. you gave us

```
QPushButton:pressed#login {
    background-color: #59b75c;
}
```

but this does not work.

The correct way to do it is

```
QPushButton#login:pressed {
    background-color: #59b75c;
}
```

also, be sure that after the '#' you use the objectName of the pushButton and not the text of the button.

Here is a link with some [styleSheet examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html)